# Taking until nth element in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

How can i take first nth element into another list ?

for example first 4;

(taking-first 4 list newlist)

list: '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
newlist: '(1 2 3 4)

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the nth by taking the first and then taking the (n-1)th from the rest.

```
(define (taking-first n list)
  (if (or (null? list) (= 0 n))
      '()
      (cons (car list) (taking-first (- n 1) (cdr list)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

See if your interpreter provides the [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) procedure, it already does what you need:

```
(take '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 4)
=> '(1 2 3 4)
```